# Can I retrieve limited dataset from a CSV file in Azure Data Lake U-SQL?

Tags: azure, u-sql

Can I filter data loaded from a CSV File using `U-SQL's EXTRACT? I know we can limit the data using the where condition in the select after the EXTRACT. But, I want to filter it during the use of the 'EXTRACT'

I have huge `CSV` file. I don't want to load all of it into the first dataset itself.

e.g.
I have lot of auto claims in the dataset. I want to filter it while I 'EXTRACT' it based on a date in the dataset.

Comment: Yes of course - can you please provide some sample data and expected results though?  Please also explain the rules you want to govern the filter.

Comment: Sorry..updated the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. However only column pruning can be pushed into the extractors. Since there is no semantics assigned to the data before you extract it with the Csv extractor, filters will be applied on the generated rowset. There are many examples out there that show you how to do so. [Here](http://aka.ms/usql-hol) is an example from one of the hands-on-labs.

Comment: Hmm..ok. Looks like I got to load all the data into the rowset and then apply the filters. Thank you.

Comment: It does not make that much of a difference whether you do the filter inside the extractor or outside as long as the filter is executed in the same vertex. In order to filter you will have to read the file anyway since a csv file has no internal indices or clustered organization of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can filter data loaded from csv file. You can do something like this:

```
 @log =
     EXTRACT UserId          int,
             StartDate       DateTime,
             Location        string,
              ....
              ....
             Url             string
     FROM "/Samples/Data/Log.csv"
     USING Extractors.csv();

 @result =
     SELECT Location, Url, StartDate
     FROM @log
     WHERE StartDate >= DateTime.Parse("2017/01/6") AND StartDate <= DateTime.Parse("2018/06/08");

 OUTPUT @result   
 TO "/output/cleanlog.csv"
 USING Outputters.Csv();
```